# How to press Ctrl + Shift in Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to change the text direction in the google search box from (right-to-left) to (left-to-right) using selenium before actually sending keys to it.

Google automatically sets the direction (right-to-left) because of my location and language.

i tried this code

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com.eg/");
WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
box.click();
actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).sendKeys("abcd").perform();
```

But no matter what it doesn't work i also tried :

```
box.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL, Keys.LEFT_SHIFT));
```

I can't seem to find a way in Selenium to press only 2 modifier keys without letters and get results

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.build()` so that your code will be

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com.eg/");
WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
box.click();
actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).sendKeys("abcd").build().perform();
```

And if this still not work try adding an explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
driver.get("https://www.google.com.eg/");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("q")));
WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
box.click();
actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).sendKeys("abcd").build().perform();
```